# How to set environment variables so they work in non-interactive bash shells?

Tags: java, linux, gradle, redhat, amazon-linux-2

I am running the `amazonlinux:2` docker image directly from dockerhub and installing the corretto-17 JDK with the following command:

```
yum install -y git java-17-amazon-corretto-devel
```

Note: I am not using a custom `Dockerfile`, I do not control it and I can't change it.

When I then try and run my `.gradlew` task, it fails because there's no `JAVA_HOME` set.
So I do that by:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64'" >> /root/.bashrc
```

If I manually connect a terminal to to the container, the `.bashrc` works fine and `gradlew` will run.

But when I run commands from outside the container via something like:

```
docker exec kopibuild /bin/bash -c "cd the-project-code && ./gradlew build"
```

The `.bashrc` is not loaded so `JAVA_HOME` is not set and `gradlew` fails.

My workaround is to add the interactive flag `-i` to the `bash` command and then it all works, but there are warnings in the logs about "cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device".

```
docker exec kopibuild /bin/bash -c "cd the-project-code && BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc ./gradlew build"
```

But it didn't seem to do anything.

What's the right way to set environment variables for Amazon Linux so they will exist in non-interactive shell invocations?

Comment: You can set envvar(s) in `docker exec` using `--env/-e` or `--env-file` (in the host); see the man page. Or you can make `bash -i` happy by having exec allocate a pty with `-t`; ditto. None of these are specific to AmazonLinux. If your projectdir/gradlew is a script, check if its first line is a 'shebang' for /bin/sh or similar -- that runs bash in a POSIX-like mode where BASH_ENV is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around on the Googles - I believe there is no standard *Linux* way to set an environment variable for **non-interactive** shells.

But there is a *Docker* way to answer the question. On the original `docker create` of the container from the `amazonlinux:2` image, specify the environment variable via `-e JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64`.  This stores the environment variable in the docker metadata for the container and it will be available in all execution contexts, including non-interactive shells invoked directly via `docker exec` (without having to specify it explicitly for every `exec` command).

As far as I know, this is the same as what the `ENV` command in a `Dockerfile` does.